# cakePHP point to right app

Tags: php, cakephp, directory

I have two "apps" in my cakePHP folder, how do I tell Cake to retrieve content from  "another_app"?

```
/app
/another_app
```

Comment: Perhaps, if you change the APP_DIR value in config.php it will be enough. But I'm not sure.

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve? Static assets or PHP scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to have 2 APP_DIR's on the same cakephp installataion. However, to change the value of APP_DIR in index.php

```
// /app/webroot/index.php (partial, comments removed)


if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define ('APP_DIR', 'another_app');
}
```

More info http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html#advanced-installation

Comment: But if he do that then he will not be able to access to assets of `app`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CakePHP standard approach: [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html), but this only retrieve assets within your `app` directory (not necessarily `webroot`). And you could try [MeioUpload](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/), some of its features say:

`* Accepts custom directory for files to be uploaded;`

so I think you should check it out.

**EDIT**

Do you want to retrieve assets from both app's ? Or just have two apps and have enable one of them?